# How to save BlockingQueue Data into Simple Array?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have class that stores live video feed from webcam in the bitmap form by using BlockingQueue and on the other hand the ImageView take those  bitmaps and give me the preview of the webcam.
But unfortunatly i am not able to save those bitmaps in a arrays for further processing.

```
public void LiveData(LiveViewData data){

    BlockingQueue<LiveViewData> bounded   = new LinkedBlockingQueue<LiveViewData>(9);


    try {
        bounded.put(data);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap[] DataImage = new Bitmap[145];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
    {
        try {
            DataImage[i] = bounded.take().bitmap;
            work.setImageBitmap(DataImage[i]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        Bitmap bmp =  bounded.take().bitmap;
     //   work.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why are you not able? whats your code?

Comment: @pskink can you tell me how to store BlockingQueue Data into Simple Array, I am using LinkedBlockingQueue and i am getting 16 frame per second.

Comment: iterate over all elements of your `BlockingQueue` and copy each item to your array, whats the problem in that simple `for` loop?

Comment: @pskink when i am using  BlockQueue.take() i am getting more than one bitmap file.

Comment: no, it takes one element: *"Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available."*

Comment: @pskink This is how my code look like

Comment: add your code to your question, not here, in comments

Comment: what is 145? what is 9?

Comment: 145 is the size of my array and 9 is the capacity of my BlockingQueue.

Comment: so whats wrong with that for loop?

Comment: @pskink Loop hangs the application.

Comment: hangs? do you have 9 items in your queue? did you try to print its size with `Log.d`?

Comment: pskink i tried Blockqueue.size() and it showing 1

Comment: so you have the answer why it hangs: "Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, **waiting** if necessary until an element becomes available."

Comment: @pskink it shows 1 element but you are right because  this line of code 
Bitmap bmp =  bounded.take().bitmap;
consumes that bitmap and therefore it has no more element to store in a bitmap array so it got hang.